# Is it wrong to answer admittitng that you are guessing?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

A few days ago I posted an [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/83201/68764) (now deleted by moderator) to [Technology that can survive a “Rubber-Hose attack”](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83026/technology-that-can-survive-a-rubber-hose-attack)

A comment was left:

> Felipe - this post has too many flags as 'not an answer' - and the
>   comments you have received agree. I'll delete, but feel free to leave
>   a post which does answer, rather than guess.

I understand that it would be better to post an answer without guessing, but in this case I think that won't be possible due to the nature of the question.

Even the second most upvoted answer starts by clarifying:

> All of our answers are speculation, of course, ..

So, was using the word ***guess*** what lead to the deletion or the answer?

**EDIT**: maybe the key is the word ***exist*** in the question (*What technology/methods exist that would...*), in which case my answer fails since I don't know if the technology I mentioned exists, but still, some other answers there have the same flaw, so I don't get why only this one got deleted.

For those who can't see the deleted answer:

[image]

Comment: The "Guess" of the other answers is referring to an interpretation of what Snowden said, not whether or not the technology/method that they propose in their answer exists

Comment: @user2813274 I also answered based on what Edward said

Comment: The problem is your also guessing as to technology that doesn't exist (or you haven't shown it existing), whereas the others all use well-known systems to give a possible explanation

Comment: @user2813274 are the [stack of cash](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/83157/68764) or the ["self-destroy-if-wrong-key"](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/83146/68764) well-known systems?

Comment: the self-destroy-if-wrong isn't a well-known system, thus all the down-votes on that answer.. the stack of cash is really just the input to a standard encryption system, it and it is explained in enough detail such that one can use it if they wanted to.

Comment: @user2813274 I'll leave the stack-of-cash out for now, so, we agree 'self-destroy-if-wrong' isn't something that exists and is also guessing, thus the downvotes (like my answer); I flagged it (using the same flag my answer received) and the flag was immediately disputed, so I'm still confused about how things should work

Answer (score 3):

No, the reason for deletion was not the guess. The comments seemed to give perfectly clear reasons for all the flags. I just added my comment to you to help steer you.

@schroeder tried to help guide you

The comments attached to your post are as below:

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21816/discussion-between-rory-alsop-and-felipe-pereira).

Comment: after all it seems like the discussion didn't continued in the chat, I answered what you asked there @RoryAlsop